# C++: How to debug 'bus error' using lldb?

Tags: c++11, lldb

I'm new to `lldb` debugging. Recently, I compiled my code and tried to test it. After compilation when I run it, I get '**Bus Error**'. So, I thought to use `lldb` debugger to find out the problem. The terminal gives me output like this:

```
$ lldb ./testLSTMForwardPass
(lldb) target create "./testLSTMForwardPass"
Current executable set to './testLSTMForwardPass' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 96512 launched: './testLSTMForwardPass' (x86_64)
Testing LSTM Forward pass:
Process 96512 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102742ba8)
    frame #0: 0x0000000102742ba8
->  0x102742ba8: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x102742baa: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x102742bac: addb   %al, (%rax)
    0x102742bae: addb   %al, (%rax)
Target 0: (testLSTMForwardPass) stopped.
(lldb) bt all
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102742ba8)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000102742ba8
    frame #1: 0x00000001015a1768 libMatrix.so`TMatrixT<double>::operator=(this=0x00007ffeefbfdd60, source=0x0000000102742b60) at TMatrixT.cxx:1739 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x00000001015a16e8 libMatrix.so`TMatrixT<double>::TMatrixT(this=0x00007ffeefbfdd60, another=0x0000000102742b60) at TMatrixT.cxx:87 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x0000000100006cf0 testLSTMForwardPass`double testForwardPass<TMVA::DNN::TReference<double> >(timeSteps=<unavailable>, batchSize=<unavailable>, stateSize=<unavailable>, inputSize=<unavailable>) at TestLSTMForwardPass.h:98 [opt]
    frame #4: 0x000000010000695a testLSTMForwardPass`main at TestLSTMForwardPass.cxx:28 [opt]
    frame #5: 0x00007fff65722145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #6: 0x00007fff65722145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

I'm not able to understand what this output means. It would be great if anyone can help me to understand it properly. :)

Comment: The backtrace show function names, file name, and line numbers. The most recent frame is at the top (lowest number) and the oldest frame is at the bottom (highest number), so it's quite easy to follow.

Comment: No, I meant then how should I point out the specific line error? Sorry, but I'm a little confused. New to this :)

Comment: What, you mean like in the `TMatrixT.cxx:1739` part of the output? That means the crash happened in the file `TMatrixT.cxx`, line `1739`. Since it's in a library I doubt that you will find the root cause of the crash there though. Instead look few frames down the stack, in the `testForwardPass` function in the file `TestLSTMForwardPass.h` at line `98`. And in the `main` function in the file `TestLSTMForwardPass.cxx` at line `28`.

Comment: Oh, so we basically look out at code line according to frames. Thank you so much. That will be helpful. I really appreciated your help :)

Comment: `stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This is the specific reason. Also `addb   %al, (%rax)` four times in a row might provide some hint if you look up the binary representation of this opcode.

Comment: "we basically look out at code line according to frames" yes, you can do this right in the debugger. Read help on lldb basic commands.

Comment: This looks like you might be touching an object that has been freed, or something like that.  You might get useful data by running your app under the Address Sanitizer.  It requires a rebuild - the tool instruments all new's and deletes and checks all accesses - but it is great for catching this sort of error where it happens, rather than blowing up some time later on when the trail is less obvious.  If you are using Xcode, edit the Run scheme for your target, and in the Diagnostics tab, check Address Sanitizer.